# Which method is the "expensive" one when establishing a RavenDB connection

Tags: jax-rs, ravendb

I am using RavenDB in my JAX REST service, and I want to move the DB connection setup code out of the service method and into its own ServletContextListener, so that it only gets executed once on Tomcat server startup; after that, each service call should be handled by an already-existing connection. ([This](https://ayende.com/blog/4049/connection-pooling-implemention) article desrcibes how to set up a connection pool - but I'm not sure it's still applicable, being 9 years old...)

With regards to the "expensive" operations of setting up a db connection, which ones are they - out of:

```
try (DocumentStore store = ravenDBStore)
                {
                    store.parseConnectionString(ravenLocation);
                    store.initialize();
                    IDocumentSession currentSession = store.openSession();
                    ...
}
```

I suspect that it's the initialize() method, which is expensive and should be moved out of the service call code; what about openSession() ? Could that - even in theory - be shared/re-used between service calls to the REST method ?
BTW, [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) is what I'm going by to re-factor the db connection code.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DocumentStore should be treated as a singleton (one instance per app),
read [this](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/java/client-api/creating-document-store).
Initialize method creates the connection with the server, then before the initialization you can't open a new session.
Then move the creation of the DocumentStore and also its initialization.

I suggest you to open session per request considering that is a service, anyway opening new sessions hasn't a big impact on performance